# categorizing Types in bucket using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like:

DF1

```
ID      Value      Type         Date
II-1    150        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-1    175        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-1    165        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-1    168        Active       2019-01-01 15:34:18
II-2    200        InActive     2019-01-05 17:14:20
II-2    45         InActive     2019-01-05 17:14:20
II-3    34         InActive     2019-02-04 11:04:12
II-4    78         InActive     2019-02-01 12:33:14
```

I need to convert the above output in the below mentioned format in **R** to achieve the below mentioned format.

Where, the `1-3` and `3-5` are the bifurcation of count of ID basis on the bucket under which it falls as per the `Type`.

Example: If ID `II-1` coming four times then it will fall in `3-5` bucket, similarly ID `II-2` will fall in `1-3` bucket.

```
Month       Total      Active  1-3   3-5   InActive   1-3   3-5  Hold  1-3  3-5
Jan-19       6           2      1     1       0         0    0     0    0    0
Feb-19       2           0      0     0       2         2    0     0    0    0
```

Comment: Are you getting this information from a database or from in-memory data?

Comment: @mj_whales: Yes I'm getting these information from same database but different tables, And I have created a Dataframe of the query output.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: @mj_whales: MySQL using library 'RMySQL'

Comment: So just to clarify, you already know how to connect to your database and get the data, but all you need to do now is to manipulate the data you already have into the example output. Is this correct?

Comment: @mj_whales: Yes, I have also updated the question. All I want to manipulate the data in the required format.

Comment: If an ID appears 3 times, which bucket does it go toward?

Comment: @JonSpring: It would go in `1-3` bucket. Sorry, My bad. I'll change the bucketing from `3-5` to `4-5`.

Comment: @VectorJX I have edited my answer to include the totals as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the totals in as well, you can find these separately and do a join:

```
## Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


## Alter the DF1 table to get months in the right format: DF1_new
DF1_new <- DF1 %>%
  # Create new month column
  mutate(Month = as_factor(str_c(month(Date, label = TRUE), year(Date), sep = "-")),
         Type = as_factor(Type)) %>%
  # Reorder columns
  select(Month, everything())


## Group DF1_new by Month and Type: right
right <- DF1_new %>%
  # Count ID by month and type
  count(Month, Type, ID) %>%
  # Place each in buckets by count
  mutate(Bucket = case_when(n < 4 ~ "1-3", TRUE ~ "4-5")) %>%
  # Combine bucket names
  unite(Type.Bucket, c(Type, Bucket), sep = ".") %>%
  # Count how many IDs fall in each bucket type
  count(Month, Type.Bucket) %>%
  spread(Type.Bucket, n)


## Get month totals and join to month/type data frame
DF1_new %>%
  # Count ID by month
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(Total = n()) %>%
  left_join(right, by = "Month")
```

Result:

```
Month       Total    Active.4-5    InActive.1-3
Jan-2019      6        1              1 
Feb-2019      2        NA             2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough approach, could be tweaked to get the specific columns you want.

```
library(lubridate); library(tidyverse)
DF1 %>%
  count(Month = floor_date(Date, "month"), Type, ID) %>%
  mutate(bucket = case_when(n < 4 ~ "1-3", TRUE  ~ "4-5")) %>%
  count(Month, Type, bucket) %>%
  unite(column, Type:bucket) %>%
  spread(column, n, fill = 0)

## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Month               `Active_4-5` `InActive_1-3`
#  <dttm>                     <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 2019-01-01 00:00:00            1              1
#2 2019-02-01 00:00:00            0              2
```

Data:

```
DF1 <- structure(list(ID = c("II-1", "II-1", "II-1", "II-1", "II-2", 
"II-2", "II-3", "II-4"), Value = c(150L, 175L, 165L, 168L, 200L, 
45L, 34L, 78L), Type = c("Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", 
"InActive", "InActive", "InActive", "InActive"), Date = structure(c(1546385658, 
1546385658, 1546385658, 1546385658, 1546737260, 1546737260, 1549307052, 
1549053194), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Getting Error `Error in count(., Month = floor_date(Date, "month"), Type, ID) : 
  unused argument (Month = floor_date(Date, "month"))`

Comment: Added the version of DF1 I am used from the OP and converting Date to POSIXct. Do you get the same error using that as the data? Were you able to load lubridate (the source of the floor_date function)?